# How to get instanceof property (class) in wikidata SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a wikidata SPARQL query that gets all instances of type "event" (occurrence in space/time) near a particular location (e.g. Nevada):

```
SELECT ?event ?eventLabel ?date ?location
WITH {
  SELECT DISTINCT ?event ?date ?location
  WHERE {
    # find events
    wd:Q1227 wdt:P625 ?nevada. 
    ?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554.
    # with a point in time or start date
    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P585 ?date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?event wdt:P580 ?date. }
    ?event wdt:P625 ?location.
    FILTER(geof:distance(?location, ?nevada) < 400).
  }
  LIMIT 1000
} AS %i
WHERE {
  INCLUDE %i
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" . }
}
```

([link](https://w.wiki/7ELJ) to query)

How would I need to modify this query to get the "class" of which each event is an instance of? E.g. for [Q6492580](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6492580) (Las Vegas Grind), I see it is an instance of type `music festival`. I would like to have this information populated in my query results.

Comment: you should think about making use of the spatial index given that your query has horrible complexity: `SELECT ?event ?eventLabel ?eventType ?date ?eventLocation 
WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None".
  wd:Q1227 wdt:P625 ?nevadaLocation.
  SERVICE wikibase:around {
    ?event wdt:P625 ?eventLocation.
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:center ?nevadaLocation;
      wikibase:radius "400".
  }
  ?event wdt:P31 ?eventType . 
  ?eventType wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554 .
}
LIMIT 10` - it's missing your additional stuff and it might timeout given that there are 70 000 event types in Wikidata.

Comment: technically, the event type is indeed "hidden" in your property path `?event wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554.`, thus, splitting it up would be one way: `?event wdt:P31 ?eventType . ?eventType wdt:P279* wd:Q1190554.`

Comment: Thank you, both. This makes sense. Unfortunately, both modifications/queries lead to `Query timeout limit reached`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, the query is too complex to be run at once, I would always get timeouts.

My workaround now is to first query all events in an area (see question), and then loop through the items, getting all classes of all entities, e.g.:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?class ?classLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q41522095
    wd:Q116448291
    wd:Q29098186
    wd:Q29098186
    wd:Q4602566
    wd:Q16274840
  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?class.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Afterwards, to get the superclasses for events:

```
select distinct ?commonBase ?commonBaseLabel
where {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q6492580
  }
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?commonBase. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} LIMIT 5
```

| commonBase | commonBaseLabel |
| --- | --- |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q132241 | festival |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q868557 | music festival |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1190554 | occurrence |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1656682 | event |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3249551 | process |

The first superclass refers to the boradest categorization for events (which I can then use to label classes on my map).

This is not perfect, as it returns a lot of classes that have nothing to do with events, e.g. the class `mass shooting` can be considered an event, but classes `building` and `hotel` are not events. Therefore, some manual filtering is necessary. Still posting this here as a temporary solution until better suggestions are available.